# Como utilizar a estrutura "enquanto" para esse código?

Tags: algoritmo, while, visualg

Estou realizando um exercício para iniciantes em programação, ele consiste em criar um código que lê uma quantidade de idades e pergunta ao usuário se ele pretende continuar a lê-las ao chegar no último valor determinado pela variável limite, fazendo uso da estrutura "enquanto". Ele funciona quando eu estabeleço o primeiro limite de pessoas que o programa irá contar as idades, porém, quando ele pergunta se quer continuar, ele apenas repete a pergunta em um loop, o que posso fazer para resolver esse problema?

**Aqui está o código que fiz**

```
Var
 cont, limite, num, soma1, soma2, somaidade, total: inteiro
 media: real
 resp: caractere
Inicio
  cont <- 0
  soma1 <- 0
  soma2 <- 0
  somaidade <- 0
  repita
  escrevaL("Quantas idades você pretende ler?")
  leia(limite)
  limpatela
  enquanto (cont <= (limite - 1)) faca
           cont <- cont + 1
           escrevaL("Informe a",cont,"º idade:")
           leia(num)
           se (num > 0) entao
                   soma1 <- soma1 + 1
           fimse
           se (num >= 21) entao
                   soma2 <- soma2 + 1
           fimse
           somaidade <- num + somaidade
           total <- somaidade
  fimenquanto
  escrevaL("Você pretende continuar?")
  leia(resp)
  limpatela
  ate(resp = "não")
  media <- (total/soma1)
  escrevaL("A quantidade de idades digitadas foram",soma1)
  escrevaL("A média entre as idades digitadas foram ",media:4:2)
  escrevaL("A quantidade de idades de 21 anos ou mais foram",soma2)
Fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O VisualG possui uma Área das variáveis de memória (Globais e locais)
Você pode usar isso para 'debugar' o seu algoritmo. 
Após analisar o comportamento das variáveis durante a execução do programa, percebi que após o loop que lia as idades ser executado, a variável *cont* continuava com o seu último valor iterado.
[image]

Sendo assim, o loop começava a iterar sobre o valor armazenado na variável *cont*.

### Resolução

Atribuir o valor 0 à variavel *cont* após o término do loop *enquanto*.

```
...
fimenquanto
cont <- 0
...
```